# How to gunzip chunk-by-chunk in node.js?

Tags: node.js, gzip

I'm getting contents of a gzipped web page in chunks and want to decompress each as soon as it gets received, so I'm trying to do (stuff stripped for readability):

```
var decompress = function(string, callback) {
    zlib.gunzip(string, callback);
};

decompress(chunk, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

However I'm only getting `null`s logged to the console. My node version is 0.6.2 and `zlib` is the built-in one. How should I decompress it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to pipe contents to Gunzip, use `zlib#createGunzip()`

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
  var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
  res.pipe(gunzip);
  gunzip.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e)
});
```

Comment: Looks like pipe assumes Stream, what do I do if I have a Buffer?

Comment: Because you said in your question you were getting data in chunks, I assumed you were making a request with the http module and getting a res object back. If you're doing it some other non-stream object way, you can call `gunzip.write(data)`

Comment: Ok, that's working better. One final question: how do you know it? I was googling for this stuff a lot, and even if you try "node js gunzip write", the top results are SO questions...

Comment: Read through the docs ( http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/index.html ). They're really informative and actually do contain useful examples.

Comment: As for me, node's docs are the worst ever, look at the docs for http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib.Gunzip there's nothing. Not even method names. And when there are names, no return types or types of arguments are provided. Ok, I was just thinking that perhaps there's some kind of a documentation conspiracy against me, looks like there's none. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I guess I understood that `zlib.Gunzip` is a class and `zlib.createGunzip` is a shortcut for instanstiating that class because I've already used other core modules a bunch and I know how they tend to be structured. But I can see how someone who's new to node can have trouble understanding that page. That page does need a rewrite. Here's another set of docs that may help you http://docs.nodejitsu.com/ although it doesn't cover as much of the API as the official docs do.

Comment: But how do you know how to use `zlib.Gunzip`? Some stuff can be seen in the examples, but there should be a page with all public methods, their definitions and return descriptions, just like there is for Java or PHP.

Comment: I've used the http module a lot and noticed that `http.Server` is a class and what `http.createServer()` does is make a new instance of `http.Server` with its one argument. And I figured it's the same for `zlib.Gunzip` and `zlib.createGunzip()`. And as for the docs not being complete, node.js is really new compared to Java and PHP, the devs are pretty much depending on the community to update the docs because they're so busy working on development.