# Node Stream and Process Zipped Contents via FTP

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I have a large zipped file on my server 10gb+
I cannot save the zipped file on my local machine.
I want to stream the zipped contents onto my server (via FTP), unzip the contents chunk by chunk, and process each chunk/line.

Basically my challenge and question is thus: 
Can I use each stream chunk of the zipped file and unzip them independently? Or do I have to download the whole file? Is there a node library that handles this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the zipped file to a gzipped file it's possible. From what I read it's not possible with a Zip file. As stated here: [Java: Stream Contents of Zipfile via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225488/java-stream-contents-of-zipfile-via-http)

So I decided to look into using GZipped files for this, with GZip it seems fairly easy.

- [How to gunzip chunk-by-chunk in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594566/how-to-gunzip-chunk-by-chunk-in-node-js)
- http://nickfishman.com/post/49533681471/nodejs-http-requests-with-gzip-deflate-compression
- http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html

Comment: Fantastic. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

if it s only a zipped file without a zip dictionary, maybe you can try this

```
  fs.createReadStream(`${craneProjectDir}/tree`)
  .pipe(zlib.createUnzip())
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myfile'))
```

https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_createunzip_options

If it has a dictionary, which is regular for a zipped file, you can try this

https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip

As the example is pretty big, i invite you to check the [readme](https://github.com/antelle/node-stream-zip#usage)

To read / write files via FTP, i invite you to use the library from the excellent mscdex

https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp

```
  var Client = require('ftp');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var c = new Client();
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.get('foo.txt', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.once('close', function() { c.end(); });
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.local-copy.txt'));
    });
  });
  // connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
  c.connect();
```

So yeah, that should be feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to stream the contents from an outside server. This doesn't help there. :( But is still useful information :)